# Tor group of the ideal sheaves of points on a surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be an algebraic surface and $P,Q$ two points on it. Let $I_P$ and $I_Q$ denote the ideal sheaves of $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Which is the tor group $Tor^1(I_P,I_Q)$? And what about $Tor^1(I_P,I_P)$?

Comment: Can you see what they are in the affine case?

Comment: It seems to me that in the affine case $Tor^1(I_P,I_Q)=0$ if $P\neq Q$.